# Python pickle: how to read key-values pairs from pickle.loads

Tags: python, pickle

I have a **.pkl** file that I'm writing with pickle, with key-value pairs and that works.

However I was wondering how can I access the key-value pairs once I read from this file using [pickle.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads).

```
content = pickle.load(open(COOKIE_FILENAME, "rb"))
```

`content` is a dictionary (`<type 'dict'>`).

If I do:

```
for key in content:
    # this works, but I don't have the values
```

What I want to do is instead something like:

```
for key, value in content:
    # do something with keys and values
```

but if I do that, I get:

> E       ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: What's `content`? I assume it's a dict? Anyway, this is completely unrelated to pickle.

Comment: Considering the object you are loading is indeed a dictionary, then you do `content.items()`

Comment: `for key, value in content.items()`?

Comment: @timgeb thanks for saying it. The file is generated using `pickle.dump(storage.get(), open(COOKIE_FILENAME, "wb"))` where the `storage` is the content of the LocalStorage of a browser (I'm using Selenium).

Comment: @ShinDarth that's not really relevant. We need `type(content)`. Is it a dict? Is it a list of tuples? Is it an instance of some self written class?

Comment: @timgeb the type is `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: In that case, Jose and roganjosh gave you the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
for key, value in content.items():
    # do something with keys and values
```

thanks @Jose, @roganjosh and @timgeb for your help via comments.

Answer (score 1):

when doing:

```
for i in dict_object:
```

you actually iterate through keys and not values.
to reach value just use

```
dict_object[i]
```

just saying, but I think @ShinDarth 's answer is better